# Spring Boot Port Issues

Tags: spring-boot, port

I have created a single web page application using Spring boot and i have configured the port number in application.properties file.
server.port=9991
When I right click my project and click as Spring Boot App it runs fine and when i run it for the second time its throwing that port is already in use.

I am using Spring Tool Suite.

Please let me know why I am getting error.

Error Message:

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 9991 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 9991, or configure this application to listen on another port.

Answer (score 1):

The first application you started was  probably still running when you started oh the second time. Kill the process manually. Look for java processes and kill them.

Comment: yeah , your are right.So i resolved the issue by restarting the application from Boot Dashboard and it resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you can just configure `port 0` for your application to let the OS pick a port for you. So you could have multiple instances running on the same box at the same time. Porbably you will encounter more conflicting ports for management etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using eclipse IDE. when you run first time your program it will take your current port number. I think you are running your application without stop your old process. simply way in eclipse, there is your application running log. there is cross btn or red square btn  click that btn and re run that.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is quite common. Following are some of the steps you can take in this case to mitigate it

1. **Check Port Availability**

   Use a port-checking tool. Employ a tool like `netstat` (on Windows, macOS, or Linux) or `lsof` (on Linux/Unix) to verify if port `9991` is indeed occupied.
   Terminate conflicting processes. If a process is using the port, gracefully terminate it to free it up.
2. **Resolve Port Conflicts**

   Choose a different port if port 9991 is genuinely unavailable, and configure Tomcat to use an alternate accessible port.
   Stop other services if other applications are using the port, temporarily stop them to allow Tomcat to utilize it.
3. **Inspect Logs**

   Review Tomcat logs. Thoroughly examine Tomcat's log files for additional error messages or clues that might shed light on the issue's root cause.
4. **Restart Application**

   Initiate a clean restart after making any configuration changes or resolving port conflicts, and restart the application to apply those modifications.
5. **Firewall/security restrictions**

   If firewalls or security measures are in place, ensure they aren't blocking port 9991.
6. **Operating system limitations**

   Be mindful of any OS-specific constraints that might prevent the application from binding to certain ports.
7. **Specific Tomcat version**

   If you encounter unusual behaviors, explore the release notes or documentation for your particular Tomcat version for known issues or resolution steps.